# Number of elements of order 35

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many elements of order $35$ are in group $\mathbb Z_{15} \times \mathbb Z_{35}$?

I had two ideas. Firstly, I thought that numer of elements of order $5$ is $24$ and of order $7$ is $6$, so the number of elements of order $35$ should be $24 \times 6=144$. However now I think that the elements of order $35$ are in the form: $(a,b)$ where $a^{35}=1$ and $b$ is of order $35$. Then, from the Euler's totient there're $24$ possibilities for $b$, but only $5$ possibilities for $a$, which are: $z^3,z^6,z^9,z^{12}$ and the natural element. Hence there're not $144$ but $120$ elements of order $35$.

What I am doing wrong? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second count you're missing elements such as $(a,b)=(\bar3,\bar5)$ where $b$ has order $7$ (and not $35$ as you specify) but $a$ has order $5$.